# How can I disable commenting on my Facebook post?

Tags: facebook, comments

I don't want anyone, not even friends, to be able to comment on my Facebook post.

I found an option to disable comments from *subscribers* and from *friends of friends* on public posts 
[image]

I looked through Facebook's help center and settings, but could not find a way to disable comments from *friends*.

Is this possible in Facebook?

Answer (score 5):

Sorry, No such feature available in Facebook. At the most you can prevent your Friends of Friends from posting comments; your friends will have the privilege of posting comments - no matter what.